# I am having an issue regarding MIMEMultipart

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, mime, smtplib

I am trying to send emails through python and when assigning a variable to MIMEMultipart I encounter an error where I get the type error:

```
TypeError: memoryview: a bytes-like object is required, not 'MIMEMultipart'
```

I do not know why I'm getting this error, please help!
Here is my code:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

#psutil.Process(pid=28604, name='qengine.exe', status='running', started='10:39:41')

MY_ADDRESS = 'someemail@gmail.com'
PASSWORD = 'password123'
s = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
s.ehlo()
s.login(MY_ADDRESS, PASSWORD)



msg = MIMEMultipart()

msg['From'] = MY_ADDRESS
msg['To'] = 'billybobjoe@gmail.com'
msg['Subject'] = "This is a test message"

s.send(msg)
del msg

s.quit()
print('Sent!')
```

Comment: You need to call [server.send_message](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.send_message), not `server.send`.

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
s.send(msg)
```

Use

```
s.send_message(msg)
```